# C# how to change data in DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable

I'v got some problem, I use DataTable to store my data in dataGridView.
Data was inputed like this:

```
dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("par", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("max", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("now", typeof(int));

dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { id++,i + " " + j++, strarr[0], strarr[1] }); // ... etc etc

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

now I want to do some changes, I use code:

```
dt.Rows[1].ItemArray[3] = "VALUE";
```

When I debug, ItemArray represents the row I want to, so its okey, but still I can't do any changes, whats wrong ? How to update DataTable ??? I'm googling and nothing :(

Answer (score 50):

Try the SetField method:

`table.Rows[i].SetField(column, value);`
`table.Rows[i].SetField(columnIndex, value);`
`table.Rows[i].SetField(columnName, value);`

This should get the job done and is a bit "cleaner" than using Rows[i][j].

Comment: +1 - I agree, your suggestion is much cleaner than the examples using an array.  Your example allows clear identification of the field by name, rather than implied field by position in an array.  I think the use of the array is cheap and lazy.  It most certainly raises risk of errors during future maintenance.  Also, if the data table object is derived from a database structure, and if that database structure where to change, such as inserting a column in the middle of the table definition, the use of the array method would potentially yield a run-time error or worse - undetected corrupt data.

Answer (score 18):

`dt.Rows[1].ItemArray` gives you a copy of item arrays. When you modify it, you're not modifying the original.

You can simply do this:

```
dt.Rows[1][3] = "Value";
```

ItemArray property is used when you want to modify all row values.

ex.:

```
dt.Rows[1].ItemArray = newItemArray;
```

Answer (score 8):

You should probably set the property `dt.Columns["columnName"].ReadOnly = false;` before.

Comment: Should be dt.columns[n].ReadOnly