# Ways to alter a DataTable in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime, datatable, formatting

I will try to explain my situation as clear as possible.

I have a DataTable containing several data that will later generate a report. One of its columns is of type DateTime. The problem is that when the report displays the dates, they are displayed in the long format "10/14/1996 12:00:00 AM" and they need to be shown in the format
"DD-MMM-YYYY".

I have tried several things to change the value in the dataTable to the desired format.
I tried this:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DateTime cellValueDateOfBirth=Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i][indexDateOfBirth]);
                string formattedDateOfBirth = cellValueDateOfBirth.ToString("DD-MMM-YYYY");
                dt.Rows[i].SetField(indexDateOfBirth, formattedDateOfBirth);
                dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.SetValue(formattedDateOfBirth, indexDateOfBirth);
             }
```

Which doesn't work, because then when I debug, I see that the value of

```
string test = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[indexDateOfBirth].ToString();
```

Was not set to the value of formattedDateOfBirth, as I expected. And the report is still generated with unformatted dates.

I've tried a few more ways to change the value of that date but without success.

I really don't care about all the dateTime data, so I was thinking that it would be a good Idea (In case it is not possible to simply change the values of the date column) to create an array with all the formatted values, and then find a way to delete the column with unformatted dates and replace it (in its original position, if possible) with the new array created with the formatted dates. 
I already created the array, but have no idea about how to replace the column values with the values in the array. Here's what I have so far:

```
                string[] FormattedDatesOfBirth = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DateTime cellValueDateOfBirth=Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i][indexDateOfBirth]);
                    string formattedDateOfBirth = cellValueDateOfBirth.ToString(EMR.HelperClasses.Core.chsDateFormat);


                    FormattedDatesOfBirth[i] = formattedDateOfBirth;

                }
                //then here I would create a column with the data in FormattedDatesOfBirth[]
```

Some other Idea is to make a copy of the DataTable, but not copying the unformatted columns and adding instead, the array of formatted values.

Do you think this is possible? Is there another way to do this? Maybe I tried changing the values in a wrong way...

I am really not sure if there is any other better solution, I will gladly hear all of your suggestions, I am out of ideas on this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: don't change in DataTable! format in report!

Comment: @MitchWheat I don't know how :( It is a DevExpress XtraReport.

Comment: @AlexTerreaux http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/CustomDocument2162

Comment: Have you tried, cellValueDateOfBirth.ToString("DD-MMMM-YYYY"); yet?

Comment: Uh... do you know if I can create a DataSource directly from a GridView? Or update a Gridview's dataSource to contain exactly the values of the gridview?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the posts in [C# how to change data in DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666087/c-sharp-how-to-change-data-in-datatable) to see if any of them apply to you? Particularly https://stackoverflow.com/a/9998257/1520364

Cant you just use [ToShortDateString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx) function to directly output the `DateTime` object as you want it? Alternatively use this overload of [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) to provide the format you want, similar to what Brian suggests.

Comment: Oh, I understand... Do you have an Idea on how to solve this?

Comment: @AlexTerreaux I have added a few alternatives to my answer.

Comment: Hmm I can't use the  ToShortDateString function on it, it won't let me. And also, if I use the ToString("DD-MMM-YYYY") overload, it will return a string and then, what you explained in your answer will happen. If i try to apply that to the DateTime Object itself, it won't work, since it I am not assigning that string to the object.

Comment: @AlexTerreaux I am not too sure about my answer now because your code suggests that you are generating the DateTime from the string in your DataTable. Is it possible to call it with that function directly when using the data, instead of pre processing?

Comment: @AlexTerreaux I am saying my answer is likely wrong. I have updated it. Meanwhile i was suggesting using the function to output when you need the value, instead of needing to change the data table first.